# Centering a div horizontally with another left-aligned sibling div with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to center one div horizontally while keeping another one in the left, as shown in the image below:

[image: div A on the left and div B centered]

I managed to obtain the desired layout, shown above, by mixing a flexbox approach (to center the B div) while also using `position: absolute; left: 20px` on div A (and setting the parent container to `position: relative`), but I don't like using `position: absolute`, feels like ancient styling.

**How to do this with pure flexbox, without `position` tricks?**

*Note that the sizes of the inner divs (A) and (B) are **not known a priori** and ideally the width of the divs should fit to content (as shown above).*

Comment: all the possible way including position:absolute are within the duplicate. By the way there is no clean way to do this, all are hacks (only the grid one is not a hack)

Comment: @TemaniAfif - I see, thank you very much! Sorry for asking a duplicate. I tried to search but didn't find anything. I guess my bad luck was that the duplicate involved "right" instead of "left".